# Hibernate Auto-Increment not working

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, composite-key

I have a column in my DB that is set with Identity(1,1) and I can't get hibernate annotations to work for it.  I get errors when I try to create a new record.

In my entity I have the following.

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="dbo", name="MemberSelectedOptions")
public class MemberSelectedOption extends BampiEntity implements Serializable {

    @Embeddable
    public static class MSOPK implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Column(name="SourceApplication")
        String sourceApplication;

        @Column(name="GroupId")
        String groupId;

        @Column(name="MemberId")
        String memberId;

        @Column(name="OptionId")
        int optionId;

        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator="native")
        @Column(name="SeqNo", unique=true, nullable=false)
        BigDecimal seqNo;

        //Getters and setters here...

    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    MSOPK pk = new MSOPK();

    @Column(name="OptionStatusCd")
    String optionStatusCd;

    @Column(name="EffectiveDate")
    Date effectiveDate;

    @Column(name="TermDate")
    Date termDate;

    @Column(name="SelectionStatusDate")
    Date selectionStatusDate;   

    @Column(name="SysLstUpdtUserId")
    String sysLstUpdtUserId = Globals.WS_USER_ID;;

    @Column(name="SysLstTrxDtm")
    Date sysLstTrxDtm = new Date();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="option")
    List<MemberSelectedVariable> variables = 
                             new ArrayList<MemberSelectedVariable>();

        //More Getters and setters here...
}
```

But when I try to add a new record I get the following error.

Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'MemberSelectedOptions' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.  I don't want to set IDENTIY_INSERT to ON because I want the identity column in the db to manage the values.

The SQL that is run is the following; where you can clearly see the insert.

```
insert into dbo.MemberSelectedOptions 
  (OptionStatusCd, 
  EffectiveDate,
  TermDate, 
  SelectionStatusDate, 
  SysLstUpdtUserId, 
  SysLstTrxDtm, 
  SourceApplication,
  GroupId,
  MemberId, 
  OptionId, 
  SeqNo) 
values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I've updated the post to include the entire file without getters/setters.

Comment: I think, we should make Hibernate not to insert `SeqNo`. Possible marking of `SeqNo` getter as `@Id` and not using `generator` will help.

Comment: I've tried setting insertable=false and updateble=false, but that didn't help.

Comment: Furthermore, i've got a composite key, so i can't set it as @Id

Answer (score 2):

When you use `@Embeddable` or `@EmbeddedId`, the primary key values are supposed to be **provided** by the application (i.e. made up of non generated values). Your `@GeneratedValue` annotation is just ignored.

Comment: This was my original setup, and it produced the same error.  I got the "native" suggestion from another SOF post.

Answer (score 1):

this combination works great for me:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example to do it

```
@Id
@Column(name = "col_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long             colId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible you need to mark your field with `@id` and not specify `generator` property.

As showed in [Hibernate Annotation - 2.2.3.1. Generating the identifier property](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e855), the next example uses the identity generator:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long getId() { ... }
```

Comment: My ID is composite, I've updated the post with the whole file

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Generators on composite keys

Comment: same problem with me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with 
Create table manually and everything will be ok.

```
CREATE TABLE `Forum` (
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `body` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (name,`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin2




import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class Forum implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ForumCompositePK forumPK;
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7070007885798411858L;

    @Column(length = 500)
    String body;

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public void setForumPK(ForumCompositePK forumPK) {
        this.forumPK = forumPK;
    }

    public  ForumCompositePK getForumPK() {
        return forumPK;
    }

}




import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

@Embeddable
public class ForumCompositePK implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8277531190469885913L;


    @Column(unique=true,updatable=false,insertable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }   

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



}
```